# Passing a query to a loader manager in a fragment from an activity

Tags: java, android, sql, android-fragments

I am using a LoaderManager in a fragment that populates a ListView with data from an SQLLite database using a SimpleCursorAdapter..

public class TimelineFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks { }

This fragment is "displayed" because it is referenced in the xml of the main activity.

Everything is working well, with the notifyChange in the ContentProvider CRUD actions reflecting any additions or deletions (actual CHANGES to the database).

I wish to implement a user based query function, but am having a great deal of trouble working out how to access the LoaderManager from within the MainActivity.

I need to send an sql selection string to the LoaderManager to requery the database. How do i do this from within the MainActivity?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround. I brought the fragment code to the main activity code. This avoided the referencing issue I had as the loader was local to the class.
Probably not best practice but as a hack it worked...

Answer (score 0):

You could send a  query from a loader callback onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle args).

You can see onCreateLoader takes a Bundle arg.

In an activity you initialise a loader with

getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(ID_LOADER,bundle,this);

You pass into a bundle  arguments you need to query sqllitedatabase

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

bundle.putInt("pathToUri","someData")

Then in a Loader callback onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle args)
you can access that "someData"
String uriPath=bundle.getInt("pathToUri")+"";

Then you create URI :
Uri selectQueryUri=CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(uriPath).build();
and create a  query:
getContentResolver().query(selectQueryUri,........)

dataProvider implements the query.

Don't forget to add a Bundle arg in a restartLoader as well.
If instead you pass in null the app will crash.
getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(ID_LOADER, bundle, this);